# Combine Map output for directory to one file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a requirement, where i  have to merge the output of mappers of a directory in to a single file. Lets say i have a directory A which contains 3 files.

../A/1.txt
../A/2.txt
../A/3.txt

I need to run a mapper to process these files which shud generate one output file. **I KNOW REDUCER WILL DO THAT, BUT I DONT WANT TO USE REDUCER LOGIC**.

```
                                 OR
```

Can i have only one mapper to process all the files under a directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up fuse to mount your HDFS to a local directory, then your output can be the mounted filesystem.

For example, I have our HDFS mounted to **/mnt/hdfs** locally. I run the following command and it works great:

**hadoop fs -getmerge /reports/some_output /mnt/hdfs/reports/some_output.txt**

Of course, there are other reasons to use fuse to mount HDFS to a local directory, but this was a nice side effect for us

Answer (score 0):

> Can i have only one mapper to process all the files under a directory.

Have you looked into CombinedFileInputFormat?  [Felix Ren-Chyan Chern](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2013/09/22/process-small-files-on-hadoop-using-combinefileinputformat-1/) writes about setting it up in some detail.